# Create two hashes from one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want every user to upload a profile image on sign up. I have two models, a User model, and an Image model. So how should I update the User model with a new user, and an Image model with a new image for that user with one form?

*user model*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile_image, class_name: 'Image', foreign_key: 'user_id'
end
```

*image model*

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    # do I need to put something else here to make this relationship work?
end
```

*user/new view*

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>

    # this needs to update a seperate params hash, but how?
    <%= f.file_field :profile_image %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>



    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

*user#create action*

```
def create

    @user = User.new(user_params)



    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save

        # save their uploaded image
        Image.create() # help needed here!

        sign_in @user
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Welcome, ' + @user.user_name + '!' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
   end
end

private

# how do I create a method to require certain parameters for the Image?

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_image)
end
```

Now I've actually done the hard bit of creating their image in the filesystem (via rmagick), the easy bit, simply updating the `images` table with information pertaining to this image, is where I'm struggling!

Also I know of nested forms, but I'm thinking the new image and the new user should both be created in the `users#create` action. It makes it a lot easier to see what's going on rather than if the image was created in its own `image#create` action. I was also thinking of putting the user creation and the image creation in a transaction block, but this is impossible if they were both happening in their own actions, so I do think the answer is splitting a form into two params hashes and doing something with the first hash, then doing something else with the second hash.

Comment: What's wrong with accepts_nested_attributes_for? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: That seems promising...

Answer (score 0):

Use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), it's a little hard to figure out at first, but it's exactly what you need in this case. Something like this:

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile_image, class_name: 'Image', foreign_key: 'user_id'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile_image
end
```

the view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :profile_image do |f| %>
   <%= file_field :file %>
<% end %>
```

The controller seems to be all set.

Comment: This is odd.. I have the `has_one` (not has many) relationship set up in the User model, I can even run `random_user.profile_image` in the console (though it returns nil), but when I use that `fields_for` method it's nowhere to be seen. However, if I say `fields_for :profile_images` (plural), then it appears, at least in the view. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Ah, this question fixed it (I needed to tweak the `new` action) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961168/ruby-on-rails-using-accepts-nested-attributes-for-does-not-generate-a-part-of-t?rq=1